# Creating a "video black" gap between videos

Tags: video, omxplayer, vlc, cvlc

Is it possible to play a series of video files without showing the desktop or console between each video? I would be fine with simply displaying a black screen for a split second. I do see that there are multiple questions posted about playing video files without a gap. What about a gap of just "video black?"

I'm using cvlc with a raspberry pi 4 and Raspbian Buster. I'm not married to cvlc, if there's an omxplayer solution that would be fine as well.

Comment: I’ve used Python’s pygame library to clear a black screen, then use the omxplayer wrapper to control omxplayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using:

```
setterm -blank force; cvlc -f /path/to/videos/
```

solves the problem when running cvlc from the console.